# Perl pack('H*', $value) in Python

Tags: python

I have code like below in Perl that I need to rewrite in Python:

```
    $varTmp = join( '', pack( "H*", $value ) );
    $result = $varTmp ^ $key;
    $result =~ s/\x00//g;
```

What I came up with is:

```
result =  (value.decode('hex') ^ key).replace('\x00', '')
```

For now I ended up with error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'
```

Would anybody help me do it correctly?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `string_1 ^ string_2` to do, considering `^` is bitwise xor?

Comment: @DeepSpace a bitwise xor?

Comment: For those not intimately familiar with Perl, can you explain what that code is supposed to do?

Comment: @Masklinn yes https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: @DeepSpace I meant that they might expect `s1 ^ s2` to perform a bitwise xor on the bytestrings.

Comment: @Masklinn oh, I see... well I guess we'll have to wait for OP's clarification

Comment: yes @Masklinn, the whole thing should 'decrypt' passwords

Comment: @JanFi86 Python AFAIK python doesn't do bitwise xor on entire bytestrings, you have to iterate the bytestring and xor individual bytes (as numbers), then convert back to a string. You may want to strip out nul bytes before converting back.

Comment: Thank you @Masklinn, would you help me with that please? I have no experiences with bytestrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, $value is a string of hex digits, like for example "303132", which is being converted to a string of characters represented by the hex digit pairs ("303132" -> "012"), and then xor-ed with another string, $key?

You need a slightly different approach for Python 2:

```
value = "303132"; 
key = "\0\0\0";
print "".join( chr(t) for t in ( ord(i) ^ ord(j) for i,j in zip(value.decode("hex"), key) ) if t != 0)
```

and for Python 3, where `str.decode` does not exist and `bytes.fromhex` must be used instead:

```
value = "303132"; 
key = b"\0\0\0"; # b stands for bytes
print("".join( chr(t) for t in ( i ^ j for i,j in zip(bytes.fromhex(value), key) ) if t != 0))
```

Please note that in the first snippet `key` and the result of `value.decode('hex')` are **strings**, so i and j are **characters** that need to be converted to numbers using `ord`; in the second one there is no such need - `key` and `bytes.fromhex(value)` are of type `bytes`, so i and j are already integers.

Comment: thank you @Błotosmętek, looks like I'm halfway through, but my key is something like `30anDrROdnnkl5RIFRnLÃ§pT1pNr9` and  it gives me `7b}>
9$      [e7
           -▒%`):o<Slb2bKB
partially_correct_result~▒U4JJPP)` which is partially correct result with something missiing and some additional signs, can you help me with that?

Comment: I believe the problem is that your `key` is a Unicode string (judging by the presence of "Ã" and "§"). You never said if you're using Python 2 or 3 – they differ quite seriously in handling of Unicode.

Comment: I use Python 2.7

Comment: In this case, you should probably convert your key like this: `key = key.decode('utf-8').encode('latin1')`. That is assuming it **is** in UTF-8, which may not be the case.

Comment: thank you, that worked, now I have correct result plus `7b}>
9$      [e7
           -▒%`):o<Slb2bKB` in the beginning, would you help me to get rid of that?

Comment: would you also help me please with `7b}> 9$ [e7 -▒%):o<Slb2bKB` that I get in the beginning of returned string?